# passing a string as a parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, push

I have created the following function

```
        var jsonData = <?php echo $jsondata; ?>;                            
    var objectLength = <?php echo $lines; ?>; /*length of the object*/
    var dataArray = [];
    var objectParser = {};  
    objectParser.getArrays = function(jsonData, dataType) {
        var i = 0;                          
        stringName = dataType;      
        for (i = 0; i<=objectLength; i++) {
            dataArray.push(jsonData[i].stringName);                 
        }
        return dataArray; 
    }

    var timeStamp = objectParser.getArrays(jsonData,'timestamp');

    console.log(timeStamp);
```

to take in JSON data and read the data from it. My problem is that right now I am getting a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stringName' of undefined
```

in the code which I am not sure why it's happening. Doing

`console.log(jsonData[0].timestamp)` works just fine

Here is the json data sample `[{
    "timestamp": "12\/16\/2013 0:00",
    "curr_property": "7211",
    "curr_property_cost": "123",
    "day_property": "48",
    "day_property_cost": "281",
    "curr_solar_generating": "4958",
    "curr_solar_export": "0",
    "day_solar_generated": "33",
    "day_solar_export": "0",
    "curr_chan1": "1964",
    "curr_chan2": "4958",
    "curr_chan3": "289",
    "day_chan1": "13",
    "day_chan2": "33",
    "day_chan3": "1"
}, ..........]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'stringName' of undefined` means that the previous operation gave an undefined value instead of an object.

The operation that comes right before `.stringName` is `jsonData[i]`, so this menas that `i` points to an index that doesn't exist in the JSON.

This is probably due to your loop, which goes from 0 to `objectLength` ***included***. I would change that.

Also, @Satpal's answer applies too.

Comment: datatype of objectLength is set to number and console.log(jsonData[somerandomno].timestamp) also works. What could be the problem ?

Comment: @Bazinga777 One of the problems is that your upper index limit is included (≤), the other is an incorrect usage of object property access. Again, read our two answers.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with the upper limit of the objectlength.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**Bracket Notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
jsonData[i][stringName]
```

instead of

```
jsonData[i].stringName
```

Although suggest that `jsonData[i]` undefined. Your way to access the property is incorrect

### EDIT

Also be careful with the condition `i<=objectLength`, Make sure `objectLength` is <= `jsonData.length`